# Can a stationary eye with a moving pupil exist?

Tags: entomology, eyes, vision, structural-biology

I am making a sci-fi web-comic set on an alien world and I thought up an idea for an eye that works much like an eye from a mammal, but instead of moving the whole eye, only the pupil moves. This idea sprouted from the eyes of mantis, though their moving pupil is possible because of their compound eyes, I would like to know if my idea could be physically possible. (And yes I know this is a strange question compared to others on this site).

Comment: Although this is an interesting question, it doesn't look like it can be answered without being opinion-based. Perhaps this fits better on Worldbuilding.

Comment: what do you mean with "physically possible"?

Comment: What I mean is can there be a structure capable of this function.

Comment: Also, thanks for the forum recommendation I'm new to these and your help is much appreciated.

Comment: Mmmm.... You wish to know whether theoretically an eye could exist that features a moving pupil? Everything is possible, right? I think this question is too theoretical and will give rise to primarily opinion-based answers. I vote to close.

Comment: @Jesse There is a Stack Exchange forum where questions such as yours are not only welcome, they are actively discussed. It is [Worldbuilding SE](http://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com). You should join that SE and post this question there. It is populated with creatives who are trying out ideas as well as trying to find out how scientifically accurate their ideas are. There is also a [Science Fiction & Fantasy SE](http://scifi.stackexchange.com) where this question would likely generate a discussion, but I would try Worldbuilding SE first.

Comment: @Jesse also think of the function of an eye and the pupil. The pupil is an aperture that regulates the amount of light that is allowed to enter and project onto a photo sensitive surface, it the eye's case the retina. The retina is tuned mostly in the center of the rear curve of the eyeball. Moving the pupil would change the plane of the projected image and would be reflected on a different spot on the eyeball with likely a certain amount of diffraction as the lens is still set to focus on the rear of the eye...

Comment: ... Now if your alien life forms evolved to see white light when their pupil was centered but then had other focal planes that allowed them to see more sensitively in the infrared spectrum or with another positioning and ultraviolet spectrum, then maybe a shifting pupil would be an interesting device to harness this ability. It could be analogous to night vision goggles only built into their eyes, where they can shift their pupils to see under different conditions.